# Iframe Inside JSP call Servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have a question

I have a JSP page, it has textbox and button (type is button)

when i input into textbox and click a button, value will pass to servlet and servlet handle it, after that it return value to other jsp page,

a iframe in main page will refresh to show result.

How can i do it?

Thank for your answer or suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit complicated case, but it can be done with a little imagination.

First, you need to pass your data from the jsp to your iFrame's form. This can be done using buttons `onclick` event to copy data to hidden iframe `inputs`.

```
window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('myIFrameHidenInput').value = document.getElementById('myJSPinput').value;
```

After finishing you should post, the iframe form to your servlet.

```
window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();
```

After the response comes back from the sevlet. You can display whatever you want to it.

Here is a nice resource regarding iFrames ( http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/ )